# Empty values when passing data from @Html.DisplayFor to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need pass data displayed on Razor View page by ViewModel, to Controller. Values entered by user in @Html.EditorFor are passing successfully, but data from @Html.DisplayFor for are not. What I missing?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                <div class="main-container">
                    <h3 class="main-title" id="bold-title">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EmailReceiver)
                    </h3>
                    <h3 class="main-title" id="thin-title">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PurchaseDesc)
                    </h3>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailSender, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Your e-mail", @id = "e-mail" } })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CardNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Your card number", @id = "card" } })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CardValidDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "MM / YYYY", @id = "date" } })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CVV, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "CVV", @id = "cvv" } })
                    <button class="button" id="pay-button" type="submit">
                        <div id="price">Pay @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TotalAmount)$</div>
                        <br>
                        <div id="ok">Complete!</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Comment: Look at the generated HTML for your `DisplayFor` items. The actual elements will depend on type so it will not always generate an input tag which can be submitted. [DisplayFor()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407390(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add a hidden field to get those read-only values passed back. Use `@Html.HiddenFor` to generate an equivalent hidden field.

Comment: So this hidden fields should duplicate data from @Html.DisplayFor?

Comment: Yes. I forget exactly what `@Html.DisplayFor` generates, probably something like a `<span>` or `<label>`, either of which will be passed back to the server. You need an `<input>` element if you want to pass the value back to the server.